# is there a way to add a font into assets folder and load it for html?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, custom-font

i want my text look better in [web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482556/is-it-possible-to-use-web-view-as-a-html-reader-offline) but when i try to load a font for it,it doesnt change.
according to some questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090118/using-downloaded-font-offline) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website) i found this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: "My Custom Font";
src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

i tried this for loading it from assets:

```
<style type=text/css>
@font-face {
font-family: "ROYA";
src="Roya.ttf";
}
p.customfont { 
font-family: "ROYA", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
<p class="ROYA">Hello world!</p>
```

but it doesnt working. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use : instead or =

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "ROYA";
  src: url("Roya.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

and change class name on the next code block

```
p.ROYA { 
font-family: "ROYA", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
<p class="ROYA">Hello world!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need `url()`.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "ROYA";
  src: url("Roya.ttf") format("truetype")
}
```

Comment: @MohammadRezaMajidPour Why not?  What's in your network tab?  Is `Roya.ttf` in a relative path of the CSS?

Comment: i dont know when i load it with html viewer its same as the device font

Comment: @MohammadRezaMajidPour If you can't answer basic questions about this, it isn't possible to help you.  Did you even use the font later setting the font family?  Did the font get downloaded?  Where did you put the font?  I can't read your mind, I don't know where you put your font.  Use your browser's developer tools.

Comment: i put the font in the same folder name of html

Comment: maybe its about style

Comment: i used this
    <body bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
    <div id=content>
    <p class="ROYA">my text</div></p>

Comment: i am not good at it because i am my own teacher i am still 17 but i really like to learn coding.

Comment: font works fine in other apps and its one of popular fonts in persian language.

Comment: You can't just set the class.  You still need to apply the font face to that class.